# tidyr way of expand within another group_by variable

Tags: r, split, combinations, tidyr, expand

Hi I have a dataframe with three main columns: company, product_type and product_ID. The first two column is self-explanined and the third column has ID that is global and is unique for every item.

```
input_example <- data.frame(company = c(rep("companyA", 4), rep("companyB", 6)), product_type = c(rep("shirts", 3), "pants", rep("shirts",4), rep("pants", 2)), product_ID = seq(1,10))
```

```
> input_example
    company product_type product_ID
1  companyA       shirts          1
2  companyA       shirts          2
3  companyA       shirts          3
4  companyA        pants          4
5  companyB       shirts          5
6  companyB       shirts          6
7  companyB       shirts          7
8  companyB       shirts          8
9  companyB        pants          9
10 companyB        pants         10
```

What I want is all unique combinations between shirts and pants within **each** company, and has the unique product_ID associated with them. For example of desired output:

```
>output
    company product_type.x product_ID.x product_type.y product_ID.y
1  companyA         shirts            1          pants            4
2  companyA         shirts            2          pants            4
3  companyA         shirts            3          pants            4
4  companyB         shirts            5          pants            9
5  companyB         shirts            5          pants           10
6  companyB         shirts            6          pants            9
7  companyB         shirts            6          pants           10
8  companyB         shirts            7          pants            9
9  companyB         shirts            7          pants           10
10 companyB         shirts            8          pants            9
11 companyB         shirts            8          pants           10
```

I achived this by combing split and inner_join:

```
output <- split(input_case, input_case$company) %>% lapply(., function(x){
  
  x %>% inner_join(x, by=c("company")) %>% filter(product_type.x != product_type.y)
  
}) %>% do.call(rbind,.) %>% filter(product_ID.x < product_ID.y) %>% remove_rownames()
```

Although my code can deal with this simple example, my real case data has around 100million rows of total product. I'm wondering if there is any method to accelerate this. I'm thinking parallel the `lapply` function, but it is still slow.

Thanks for any suggestions.